# Извлечение номера недели, месяца и года из JPQL запроса

Tags: jpa, java, java-ee

Как в JPQL запросе из объекта типа `DATA` (`Calendar`) вытащить номер недели, месяца и года? Это нужно для сравнения вышеперечисленных атрибутов даты.

1. Объект класса `Calendar` мапируется как `TemporalType.DATE`.
2. Использовать желательно JPQL в рамках JPA2. Если можно решить задачу только родными
       средствами какого-либо провайдера, то деваться некуда...
3. Использую `EclipseLink`, но это не принципиально.

Answer (score 1):

Взято с англоязычного [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674567/jpa-query-month-year-functions):

В *EclipseLink 2.1* воспользуйтесь вызовом `FUNC()`, позволяющим вызвать любую функцию в БД. Однако, этот вызов не входит в спецификацию JPQL:

```
FUNC('MONTH', c_Date)
```

В JPA 2.1 (*EclipseLink 2.5*) выражение [`FUNCTION`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#JPQL_function) уже является частью спецификации (и заменяет собой специфичный для *EclipseLink* вызов `FUNC`).